# call webservice and error: This error page might contain sensitive information

Tags: c#, webservices-client

I have web service with a web method "Login". I test it in my client and on the server. On my client and my server "Login" doesn't have any error and run trusly.

My server has two network card and I don't have access to second IP in my local network. I test "Login" in my client by first IP and in server by second IP and it was true.

A client in another network that it accesses to second IP have error when use "Login".

They have the below error:

```
**This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is
configured to show verbose error messages using <customErrors
mode="Off"/>. Consider using <customErrors mode="On"/> or
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/> in production environments.-->**
```

> **--.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   NationalBillingService.Login(UserInfo User)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
>   at Storm.UI.Forms.FormMainOps.clo@651.Invoke(Object[] methodParams@41)
>   at
>   .$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_2.Invoke(DoWorkEventArgs
>   dArgs)    at
>   .$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_1.Invoke(Object sender,
>   DoWorkEventArgs e)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)**

I do this setting to my web.config . it doesn't solve the problem.

```
**<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>**
```

What should I do to solve that client error?

Comment: set customErrors mode to "On", as the error suggests

Comment: btw this isn't a big deal. While you're still developing, I would advise you to keep customErrors Off so you get to see the stack trace when an error occurs. It's quite useful when debugging.

Comment: is the question why they get the 'this might contain sensitive data' warning or why you get the exception?